# Search on KeyPress on Table/ TreeTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jtree

I want to search the items on keypress event. like JTree give search on key press using following statement
 **setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);**

Does any method for JTable, JXTable, JXTreeTable ?

I do not want to add myself written code for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- this is simple possible for [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) by implements `RowFilter`, tutorial contains example about searching from `JTextField` in the `JTable`
- SwingX has own decorator for JXList, JXComboBox, JXTable (and/or  JXTreeTable???)